# Contunue writing where I left off in a csv file in C

Tags: c, fopen

I need to write **CSV** columns and row in different code section
but I can't continue where I left off

Can I do this? How can I skip the end of the document?
I tried `fseek()` but not worked.
I am putting similar code which I work on

```objectivec
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//function declaration
int fonit(int count);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a=100;
    int b=a/10;
    
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {   
        // row number
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen("fant.csv", "w+");
        // fseek( file,10, SEEK_END);
        fprintf(file, "%d", a);
        fprintf(file, ",");
        fclose(file); 
            
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            fonit(j);
        }
        
        FILE *file;
        file = fopen("ant.csv", "w+");
        // fseek( file,10, SEEK_END);
        fprintf(file, "%d", b);
        fprintf(file, ",");
        fprintf(file,"\n");
        fclose(file);
        
    }
    

    return 0;
}

int fonit(int count){
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            
            k=j%2;
        }
        
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("ant.csv", "w+");
    // fseek( file, -10,SEEK_END);
    fprintf(file, "%d", k);
    fprintf(file, ",");
    fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am fully open to different command or C++ :)

Comment: Open the files *once* before the loop, and don't close them until the loop is finished.

Comment: Try to use "a+" instead of "w+" as file open mode.

Comment: Corresponding to the manual (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) the file is truncated if you use the "w+" parameter. The + doesn't mean add some data byte allow read+write.

Comment: By the way, the code you show should not even build, much less run. How many times to you define the `file` variable in the same scope? How many times can you define a variable?

Comment: Always check if `fopen` succeeds.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it doesn't matter unfortunatelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to append to a file instead of overwriting it ("continue where I left off"), you have to open the file in append mode instead of in write mode. Append mode appends to the file, while write mode overwrites it. So, the fix would be to change `w+` in your call to `fopen` to `a+`. I recommend you to leave out the plus sign in the open mode, because, firstly, you don't read from the file at all (so don't need it), and secondly, you should not use the same file object for reading *and* writing, because that can lead to unexpected behaviour, because it makes it easy to get muddled with where you currently are in the file. Instead, if you have to do reading *and* writing, first open the file in read mode, do the reading, close it. Then, open it again in write mode, do your writing, close it.